# How to send video to discord bot python from Youtube

Tags: python, video, discord, bots, discord.py

I am working with python discord bot. I need to send video from Youtube. I have only url to this video. Please, help me.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more? What I understand is the user enters URL, and you want the bot to send a video?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: An issue with this would be discord limits files to 8mb. However, I will leave an answer that will work assuming the bot does not abide by the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the 8mb file limit on discord is not present. Then you would want to first download the youtube video and then send it on the discord channel. You will need pytube.

```
pip install pytube
```

```
from pytube import YouTube 
  
#where to save 
SAVE_PATH = "E:/" #to_do 
  
#link of the video to be downloaded 
link="https://www.youtube.com/"
  
try: 
    #object creation using YouTube which was imported in the beginning 
    yt = YouTube(link) 
except: 
    print("Connection Error") #to handle exception 
  
#filters out all the files with "mp4" extension 
mp4files = yt.filter('mp4') 
  
yt.set_filename('trial') #to set the name of the file 
  
#get the video with the extension and resolution passed in the get() function 
d_video = yt.get(mp4files[-1].extension,mp4files[-1].resolution) 
try: 
    #downloading the video 
    d_video.download(SAVE_PATH) 
except: 
    print("Some Error!") 
print('Task Completed!')
```

and on your discord.py file:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def send(ctx):
    area=ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_file(area, r"c:\location\of\the_file_to\send.png",filename="Trial",content="Message test")
```

Comment: Thank you. But can I do it without saving?